# Adding column to Oracle OLTP table

Tags: oracle, alter-table, ora-00054

I'm attempting to add a nullable column to a frequently used table in an Oracle 10 OLTP database while the application is running and busy.  Adding a nullable column is only a data dictionary change and therefore any table lock is only held for a short period of time (which can be handled by the system).

The problem is that my `ALTER TABLE` often fails with this:

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
```

My current approach is to bludgen the change in by running it until there happens to be no locks on the table.  This means I can't run such a script in SQL*Plus in full, but need to copy and paste each statement and make sure it works.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Bear in mind that it will de-compile anything (views, packages, triggers etc) dependent on the table, which might not be so good in a production environment....

Comment: +1 for cagcowboy's comment.  Not good for code to do alter tables in prod environment, a lot of invalidated objects potentially.  Its a change control issue that needs to be coordinated

Comment: 11g has improved the recompilation situation a bit, with lower level tracking of dependencies.

Comment: Some objects are invalidated and recompiled automatically when next used.  Better than shutting down the application to have a short pause.  There are not huge amounts of PL/SQL so this does not take long.  The application handles ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a brute force approach? Put it in an infinite loop and exit it when done. Pseudocode(haven't checked it):

```
create or replace 
procedure execDDL(ddl in varchar2) is
   myexp EXCEPTION;
   pragma exception_init (myexp, -54);
begin

 loop
   begin
      execute immediate ddl;
      exit;
   exception
      when myexp then 
         null;
 end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: +1, though I would add a call to [dbms_lock.sleep](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i997212) so that your block doesn't monopolize resources needlessly (a short wait between two tries).

Comment: I guess I could do this, but it does not seem very elegant